# Trying to Dynamically create Textinput in react native

Tags: react-native

I am creating a Todo App to practice what I have learned. I got to a point where I am trying to dynamically create a textinput when the user presses a button. However, I have been stuck for a while now and haven´t been able to figure it out. Here is my code. Any help is much appreciated. My main issue is the handle of the user input with the creation of the textinput and how to handle it.

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Button, TextInput, ScrollView} from 'react-                    
native';
import {Constants} from 'expo';
import FormNewTodo from '../components/FormNewTodo'


const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
appContainer: {
 flex: 1,
 paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
 backgroundColor: 'white',
 },
 form: {
 padding: 10,
 borderColor: 'black',
 borderWidth: 1,
 },
})

let id = 0


export default class AddTodoForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
   titleText: '',
   formItems: [],
   }


  handleAddTodo = () => {
    this.setState({
      formItems: [...this.state.formItems, {id: id++, text: ''},],
     })
     };

  handleformItemsChange = text => {
 // pass the formItems state to a variable       
 let newArray = [...this.state.formItems];
 let item = [];

  /*Check if it´s the beginning of a new input or to check if the 
  user is going to an old input to edit it*/
  if (text.length === 1) 
  {
  item = newArray.filter(item => item.text === '')}
   else {
   item = newArray.filter(item => item.text === text[text.length - 1])}

  //pass the item to the right element in the array and the update 
   state
 let index = item[0].id;
 item[0].text = text;
 newArray[index] = item;
 this.setState({ formsItems: newArray });
 }



 handleFormTitleChange = titleText => {
  this.setState({titleText: titleText})
  }


  handleSave = () => {
   this.props.onSubmit(this.state)
   let id = 0
   };

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
       headerTitle: 'TO DO´s',
       headerRight: (
         <Button
           title="Add"
           onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddTodoForm')}
          />
         ),
        };
       };


 render() {
   return (
    <View>
      <View>
       <TextInput style={styles.form} 
                value={this.state.titleText}
                onChangeText={this.handleFormTitleChange}
                placeholder={'Title'}/>
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
    {this.state.formItems.map(item => <FormNewTodo 
                key={item.id}
                onChangeText={this.handleformItemsChange}
                value={item.text}
                />)}
    </ScrollView>
    <Button onPress={this.handleSave} title='Save'/>
    <Button onPress={this.handleAddTodo} title='Add Todo'/>
 </View>
  )
  }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically" create text-input? What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: I am trying to have create a textinput every time the user press the button ¨Add Todo¨. I was able to do that. My issue is that I am not able to update the text inside the textinput because I can´t find the way to keep track of which textinput is been updated by the user. Sorry if my explanation doesn´t make sense, English is not my first language.